# Image editing implementation allowing undo and continuing edit like Instgram

Tags: ios, image, instagram, core-image

I am writing an iOS image editing app. Suppose there are several tools that can be applied onto an image, such as filters, blurs, vignette. etc. A naive approach is like the follows: every time a tool is applied, the old image is replaced by the new one, and the next tool is applied to the new image as if it is the initial one.

However, such approach will not allow user to edit parameters for intermediate tools.

For example, given a image A, and a user applies tool T1 with parameter P1, T2 with P2, T3 with P3 consecutively. Now it is impossible for him to change P1.

Note that Instagram iOS app supports editing intermediate parameters, so I am wondering how to implement it?

I can come up with the following approach:

Store the tools chain applied on the image, and every time we calculate the result image from the initial image.

However, I believe it is very inefficient.

So could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving one original image you can have several intermediate versions ready to be restored and used to perform only the edits that were done after the snapshot. Depending on the number of editing operations and whether you want to support saving the workspace and being able to load it later, you might want to implement background creation of such intermediate image versions that a user can quickly roll back to. The number and position of such states would depend on the available resources and whether you do or do not show the edits list and let user jump to any previous state.